# How to augment data in-memory?

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I try to understand Keras data generators for augmenting the data. What I want is an in-memory augmentation of the data. Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45612884/saving-keras-augmented-data-as-a-numpy-array) I tried some code myself and came up with this:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=40,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,)

X_data = [X_train]
y_data = [y_train]
extra_factor = 3
batch_size = X_train.shape[0]
for i in range (extra_factor):
    for X_batch, y_batch in datagen.flow(X_train, y_train, 
                                         batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True,
                                         seed=41
                                        ):
        X_data.append(X_batch)
        y_data.append(y_batch)
        break

X_data = np.concatenate(X_data)
y_data = np.concatenate(y_data)
print ('X_data.shape =', X_data.shape, 'type =', X_data.dtype)
print ('X_data.shape =', y_data.shape, 'type =', y_data.dtype)
```

In order to ensure that in any case the original data is in the training set I initialized the data list with the original data, but maybe this is superfluous. Does this code yield an array with really different data? I have no way of checking this, except that I see that the shape is increased as might be expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. But note that you do not need to manually assemble the dataset as you're doing in the for-loop. `flow()` will simply yield batches indefinitely (i. e. until your `model.train_generator()` stops).

You can check the generated samples by saving them in files. Simply use the following parameter to `flow()`:

> **save_to_dir:** None or str (default: None). This allows you to optimally
>   specify a directory to which to save the augmented pictures being
>   generated (useful for visualizing what you are doing).

Comment: Thank you! I noticed that when I feed a train generator into the model my GPU is not 100% utilized, that's why I want to experiment with in-memory augmentation. I will try to use the save_to_dir for inspection.